# How to pass array of HTML elements or string to Angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

Usual caveat: new to Angular, but lots of React experience.

I'd like to be able to pass an array of HTML elements to a component via the `@Input()` decorator. Specifically, I'm building a button group component, and the "body" of each button could theoretically be either text or an icon. So from the parent, I would want to do something like this:

```
<app-button-group [options]="[<i class='fa fa-arrow'></i>,<i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i>,<i class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i>]"></app-button-group>
```

...but I'd also like this same component to be able to accept this input:

```
<app-button-group [options]="['one','two','three]"></app-button-group>
```

In React, this is a fairly simple matter, and even an encouraged pattern. I can't see how to do this in Angular. Is this a legit pattern, or do I need to figure out another way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into content projection. You will finds lots of resources on how to do it. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thanks for this, but it's not quite what I'm after. I know ng-content allow you to compose components similar to React, and I'm already using it in a few places.  However, in this case, I'd like the @Input() to take either an HTML element OR a string (e.g. text for a button, or an icon). If it were just passing icons, then I'd probably go with the ng-content pattern.

Comment: Working with HTML elements directly is generally frowned upon in Angular. In this particular case I would declare the binding to be something like `Array<{ type: "icon", className: string } | { type: "text", content: string }>` and render the icons _inside_ the component.

Comment: It is also common to introduce a component for the icon and pass it through the [`ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) instead of an input.

Comment: @skink Thanks for the reply. That's kind of a nuisance, at least when coming from a React way of seeing the world. It seems quite a bit more limiting, and almost suggests that I'd be better off having two completely separate components: one for text buttons, and one for icon buttons. `ContentChildren`, at a glance, looks pretty cool, but if I'm reading it correctly, it relies on the parent knowing what type of children it's got, so using `ContentChildren` might not be the right thing for what I'm after. But it looks cool, though.